# Is there a way to use an arduino’s (or a seeeduino xiao’s) io pins as a 1MHz clock?

Tags: arduino

I’m building a (very) simple computer on a breadboard, and in order to finish it, I need a 1MHz crystal oscillator, which is still in the mail. Since I don’t really want to wait another two months for just one component, is there a way I can have my arduino uno or seeeduino xiao act as a 1MHz oscillator?
P.S. I tried googling it, and I couldn’t really find anything that looked like it would be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino UNO has ATmega328P running at 16MHz.

The microcontroller has Timers with PWM feature that can be used to output square wave on some pins.

To generate 1MHz signal, you should toggle a pin each 8 clocks (2MHz).

This code will output 1MHz signal on pin 9 on Arduino UNO (OC1A/PB1 on ATmega328P):

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  // stop timer
  TCCR1B = 0;
  // Toggle OC1A on match, CTC mode with TOP=OCR1A
  TCCR1A = 0x40;
  // clear timer
  TCNT1 = 0;
  // set to toggle each 8 cycles
  OCR1A = 7;
  // CTC mode with TOP=OCR1A, clock source=clk_{I/O}/1
  TCCR1B = 0x09;
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Will this work as clock input for a 6502 cpu though?